# What is the dimension of the quotient of Lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $G$ be a $g$-dimensional Lie group and $H$ be an $h$-dimensional normal Lie subgroup of $G$. Is the dimension of the quotient group $G / H$ always $g-h$? This seems intuitively true, but I can't find such a statement anywhere.

For finite groups, we have that the order of $G/H$ is the quotient of the order of $G$ and the order of $H$, which suggests that there should be a simple relationship in the Lie case as well - but of course a nontrivial Lie group doesn't have finite order, so the result doesn't directly carry over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgroup $H$ needs to be closed to ensure that $G/H$ is a Lie group. For example, let $G = S^1\times S^1$ and $H = \{(e^{2\pi i\theta}, e^{2\pi i\alpha\theta}) \in S^1\times S^1 \mid \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $\alpha$ is a fixed irrational number. While $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$, the quotient $G/H$ is not Hausdorff (the cosets of $H$ are dense in $G$ so the quotient topology on $G/H$ is the trivial topology) and therefore cannot be a Lie group.

It is worth noting that $G/H$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $g - h$ even if $H$ is not normal (as long as it is closed); of course, $G/H$ is not a Lie group in this case. The following is from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition).

> **Theorem $\mathbf{21.17}$ (Homogeneous Space Construction Theorem).** Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. The left coset space $G/H$ is a topological manifold of dimension equal to $\dim G - \dim H$, and has a unique smooth structure such that the quotient map $\pi : G \to G/H$ is a smooth submersion. The left action of $G$ on $G/H$ given by $g_1\cdot (g_2H) = (g_1g_2)H$ turns $G/H$ into a homogeneous $G$-space.

Comment: Isn't any subgroup closed by definition?

Comment: Closed under the group operation, but here closed refers to the topology.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. If $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $\mathfrak h$ is the Lie algebra of $H$, then the Lie algebra of $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$. And therefore\begin{align}\dim(G/H)&=\dim(\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h)\\&=\dim\mathfrak g-\dim\mathfrak h\\&=\dim G-\dim H.\end{align}

Comment: What about the counterexample given in the other answer?

Comment: In that example, the subgroup is not a Lie subgroup, since it is not closed.

Comment: Yes, and that seems to be a necessary assumption that you don’t state in your answer. So in general the answer is not “yes” but actually “no”, correct?

Comment: Wrong. Believe it or not, I wrote “Yes” because the answer actually is “Yes”. Who would have guessed it?

Comment: Lie subgroups are not required to be topologically closed. As Michael Albanese says in his answer, $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ in his example. These notes give the same example and explicitly say that $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/13F-Lie/Notes/Lec%2010.pdf. Your argument only makes sense under the additional assumption that $H$ is topologically closed.

Comment: You act as if there was one and only one definition of Lie subgroup. That's not true. For instance, take a look at *Foundations of Lie theory*, by A. L. Onischik and E. B. Vinberg (*Lie groups and Lie algebras I*, *Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences* **20**, Springer-Verlag, 1993). At page 9, line 1, you will find the sentence “Hence any Lie subgroup is closed”.

Comment: Okay, but if the resolution to the question hinges entirely on a definition which is not standardized in the mathematics community, then clearly one should point out that fact, instead of just implicitly choosing one particular choice of definition, and then doubling down and incorrectly claiming that your answer is correct when specifically asked about this definitional ambiguity.